# To Limit Minimum n records as Output in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, distinct, oracle12c

I've a query like below, I've given emp as a table for easy reference.

Original Query:

```
select s.* from (select distinct emp.name from emp orderby emp.id order by emp.name) s
where rownum<=20;
```

Problem:

The emp table is very huge contains billions of rows and also contains duplicate records. The above query is running for more than 1 hour eating up all DB Resources. So, to optimize the above query, I modified like below.

Modified Query

```
select s.* from (select distinct emp.name from emp orderby emp.id where rownum<=20) order by s.name;
```

Problem in Modified Query:

If suppose the name retrived for the first 20 records is same, then distinct provides only 1 record as output. But I need 20 records minimum in the output . Is there a way to achieve it?

Please note that index creation on emp.name is not allowed in our DB due to various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work better with aggregation and a `fetch` clause?

```
select name
from emp
group by name
order by name
fetch first 20 rows only
```

Comment: No, this again was running more than 40 minutes, bringing down all the resources

Answer (score 1):

The use of `select distinct` or `group by` is not going to speed up the query.  They process the entire result set.

If you don't actually need the absolute first names, you could take a sample and then apply the logic:

```
select distinct name
from (select e.name
      from emp
      where rownum < 1000000
     ) e
order by name
fetch first 20 rows only;
```

If you do need exactly the first 20 names alphabetically, then you need an index on `name` -- or a separate `names` table with all the distinct names.  I might advise you to remove the limit on the number of rows and put the results into a (temporary?) table -- there is little performance benefit to just fetching the first 20 of them.